# Find a specific vector equation of a line that divides a angle in half.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis

I've been studying a little geometry on my own, and I just recently stumbled on this problem, that I'm unable to answer:

Given the points A=(2,-1), B=(5,4) and C=(-7,8), find a vector equation of a line that divides the angle BAC in half(Same angle for each size).

Thank you

-Dom

Comment: Are you familiar with the triangle bisection theorem? You can calculate lengths $BA$, $AC$ then find the equation of a line through $BC$ and use your ratio to find the point $D$, such that the line $AD$ is what you want.

Comment: Complete the triangle ABC and draw its incircle.  The center of the circle lies on the bisector of all three angles.  So can you figure out why this is and how to locate the center of the circle?

Comment: @sdf: I've just went after it, but I don't seem to find how you could get the vector equation(even its size) out of it. I possible could you give me a example or any place I could go more into this?

Comment: Say we have lengths $m=|BA|$ and $n=|BC|$ then if $D$ is the point on the line $AC$ such that $AD$ bisects $\angle ABC$, then $|BD|/|DC|=m/n$. So you need to divide your line $BC$ up: find the point $D$ along $BC$ that gives you ratio $m/n$. Then draw a line through $A$ and $D$ - this is the required line.

Comment: @sdf - I think ["angle bisector theorem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) is a more common name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using user georg's approach:
$$
\begin{align}
u &= \frac{B - A}{|B-A|} = (0.51450, 0.85749) \\
v &= \frac{C - A}{|C-A|} = (-0.70711, 0.70711) \\
z &= \frac{u+v}{|u+v|} = (-0.12218, 0.99251)
\end{align}
$$
where $z$ is the unit vector on the desired line

$$
g(t) = t z \quad (t \in \mathbb{R})
$$

Checking the angles gives:
$$
\begin{align}
u \cdot v &= \cos \alpha \iff \alpha = 75.964^\circ \\
u \cdot z &= \cos \beta \iff \beta = 37.982^\circ
\end{align}
$$
The interesting bit is to prove, that $\beta = \alpha /2$.

In the parallelogram of $u+v$ (draw in the other diagonal $v-u$ as well) one can read from the triangle with the sides $u$, $v-u$, $v$

$$
180^\circ = \alpha + 2 \gamma 
$$

and from the triangle with the sides $(u+v)/2$, $(v-u)/2$ and $v$

$$
90^\circ = \beta + \gamma
$$

which gives

$$
\beta = \frac{\alpha}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I would say that

- normalized vectors $\vec{AB},\vec{AC}$
- their vector sum be the direction vector of the line search

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could construct this, in a way that can be turned into a computation as well.

1. Intersect lines $AB$ and $AC$ with a circle of radius $1$ around $A$. Call the resulting points of intersection $B'$ and $C'$.
2. Construct the midpoint between $B'$ and $C'$.
3. Connect that mitpoint with $A$.